# How to "conventionally" (without class syntax) call a superconstructor in javascript that enforces the use of "new"?

Tags: javascript, class, constructor

I'd like to inherit some class `MyClass` from some built-in class `Class` in the conventional way, i.e. without the new "class" syntax. I'm used to the following:

```
MyClass.prototype = Object.create(Class.prototype);
function MyClass() {
   Class.apply(this, arguments); // calling the superconstructor => "TypeError: Class constructor: 'new' is required"
   ...
}
var myObject = new MyClass(...);
```

As indicated, for many newer classes, usage of "new" with the constructor is enforced (e.g. for `MediaSource`). But `new` will be used with `MyClass` and will already have created a new object, so that I should not create yet another object inside the constructor. What am I supposed to do, or what is the equivalent here of the `super()` call in the new `class` syntax?

The only way I could think of, is to indeed create an instance with `new Class()` and explicitly return this instance from the constructor. But then the prototype of MyClass (which might have additional properties) is not really used ...

Comment: *"But `new` will be used with `MyClass` and will already have created a new object, so that I should not create yet another object inside the constructor."* That's unavoidable in this case I'm afraid, you end up throwing away the object that was originally created and using the one from your call to `Class` instead. Specifically, you do it with [`Reflect.construct`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/construct) (I'd probably pair it with a rest argument): `function MyClass(...args) { return Reflect.construct(Class, args, MyClass); }`

Comment: (The third argument tells `Reflect.construct` what the subclass is; it's so that the new object gets `MyClass.prototype` as its prototype when it's created by the base class, `Class`.)

Comment: Thanks, Reflect.construct seems really the natural way to go. However, assuming somebody would "like" to support IE-11 , one would need to do without Reflect.construct and therefore probably to manually redefine the prototype? Anyway, I've seen you had your comment previously as an answer and I was already about to accept it. So maybe you'd like to repost it as an answer ...

Comment: (I think the previous question's answers cover it.) You don't have this problem on platforms that don't have `Reflect.construct`, because they also don't have `class`. :-) So you could have a branch to handle both: `function MyClass() { if (typeof Reflect === "object" && Reflect && Reflect.construct) { return Reflect.construct(Class, arguments, MyClass); } Class.apply(this, arguments); }` *(that guard may be a bit OTT :-) )*.

Comment: "*I'd like to inherit from some built-in class Class without the new "class" syntax.*" - this is impossible.